# How to display content in a modal box with images in that box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, logic

Currently i have a detailed page listing containing all links like `page.php` contains `page.php?id=1, page.php?id=2, page.php?id=3, page.php?id=4..etc` . Now i want to just provide a preview button on which the on clicking that button without navigating to these pages, i can show the content in a popup/modal box without moving to these pages? I am stuck with this id concept that how can i achieve this. Any source/link is really appreciable.

Comment: http://fancybox.net/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform an AJAX call with jQuery based on the button that is clicked, to load the page inside your dialog:

```
$('.previewButton').click(function(){        
    // determine which page ID to load 
    // based on the button that was clicked
    var pageID = ...;

    // fetch the page
    $.get('page.php', {page: pageID}, function(data) {
        // show the page content inside the dialog
        $('.myDialog').html(data);
    });
});
```

For the dialog you could for example use jQuery UI's dialog: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

With that plugin you can simply call `$(".myDialog").dialog()` to make your `<div class="myDialog"></div>` show as a pretty dialog.

Comment: ohhh my gosh..how can i forget this ..even when even when im working on AJAX from morning :( ...Anyways thanks for answer :) ..accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could mix some ajax there there like Stardev says but if you need a simple solution try this [Url preview script](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/) (Check it please) very clean or lightbox who support iframes. A big list can found [here](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) and please check this [link](http://www.kom.cl/blogger/iframe/) to have an idea :)

For example if you try ajax i'll be something like this:
Jquery:

```
$("a").click(function() {
....
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "page.php",
           data: "id="+id,
           success: function(){
                  $('#mymodal').html('This is my image'); //Your div
           }
         }); ....
```

[Prettyphoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) HTML

```
<href="..." rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]">My image</a>
```

If you use an iframe solution:

```
<href="..." rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]">My image</a>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: ohh thats very nice combination of very useful learning stuff and code..u just missed that acceptance tick..no worries up voted :)